# How do I format a large wall of text in Python so it can be read by the computer?

Tags: python, formatting

Basically, I'm doing PythonChallenge's third challenge (#2), where I have a huge wall of symbols. I copied and pasted them into repl.it but I can't just add quotes to the end- I have to delete a space from every line to make it part of the string. Here's a tiny sample of the symbols so you can get an idea of what I'm talking about.

```
text = "%%$@_$^__#)^)&!_+]!*@&^}@[@%]()%+$&[(_@%+%$*^@$^!+]!&_#)_*}
{}}!}_]$[%}@[{_@#_^{*@##&{#&{&)*%(]{{([*}@[@&]+!!*{)!}{%+{))])
[!^})+)$]#{*+^((@^@}$[**$&^{$!@#$%)!@(&+^!{%_$&@^!}$_${)$_#)!({@!)
(^}!*^&!$%_&&}&_#&@{)]{+)%*{&*%*&@%$+]!*__(#!*)
{%&@++!_)^$&&%#+)}!@!)&^}**#!"
```

When I copy these into the editor, they do not appear as a string. How can I easily turn them into a string able to be read by the editor without deleting a space from every line? I would write a program to do that but I don't think I can, since the editor can't read them in the first place.

Comment: use docstrings -- triple quotes.  Also, what is var text?  No var keyword in python

Comment: Whoops, sorry- was still in Javascript mode. Thanks!